# Why does my NAS server not work on both Production and Isolated Lab Subnets?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, vmware-vsphere, truenas, isolated-network

In our VMWare infrastructure, I have a production network (10.1.1.0/24 subnet) and an isolated virtual lab network (also 10.1.1.0/24) which is created by Veeam, with the Veeam proxy appliance sitting between them.

I created a NAS VM (FreeNAS 9.10) with two virtual NICs, and I wanted to connect one to the production network, and one to the isolated lab network, for easy transfer of large files between the two. However, this does not work.  It seems that whichever network is connected *first* works (I can ping the VM, pull up the Web GUI, pull up the Windows Share) but when I connect the second network, the VM cannot be accessed by the second network.  Even if I set a static IP on both, and use a different 10.1.1.0/24 IP address on each virtual NIC, only the first network connected seems to work.

In my primitive understanding of networks, I'm thinking maybe the traffic INTO the NAS on that second network is working, but the NAS is trying to reply on 10.1.1.0/24 and thinks it should do so on the other virtual NIC?  Maybe this setup is impossible?  Although, that seems unlikely, since somehow the Busy Box virtual appliance/router/proxy that Veeam creates can handle a similar setup.

Comment: My workaround so far is to just keep virtually "unplugging" one of the VM NICs from one network, and plugging it into the other.  So the NAS is only connected to one network or the other.  Its annoying to have to do, but it works and is relatively quick.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same network on both NICs in your NAS is your problem. It's confused.

Comment: No way around this?  Or is this sort of a heavy linux networking/router question beyond the scope of a Q&A site?  I mean, I know the Veeam Proxy Appliance has two NICs with the same networks on them (the production 10.1.1.0/24, and the virtual test lab 10.1.1.0/24). Granted, I don't know if a web server or anything other than the gateway/proxy services would work if I attempted to access them from both networks.

Comment: You don't understand the basics of IP networking - get someone in to help you, you're out of your depth.

Comment: @Chopper3 - I assure you I at least know "the basics" and I understand what Veeam engineers were able to accomplish with their proxy appliance. I added an answer related to netfilter marked packets, which I think is the key ingredient I was missing.

Comment: @AdamNofsinger If you ever figure it out, I'd be interested to know. In fact, I think it would be worthwhile posting a question very specifically asking about this and answering it yourself for all to clearly see. This one is getting kind of messy.

Answer (score 3):

A good practise is to use different network ranges for production and lab. For example, you use 10.1.1.0/24 subnet for production and 10.1.2.0/24 subnet for lab.

Update : According to your needs, you want the NAS to be seen with the same IP adress in the prod subnet and the lab subnet. What I would do is set up NAT (on a small fw or linux box or linux VM) in front of the NAS. Therefore prod and lab with have same IP adress while still being isolated.

```
    
+------------------+
| PROD 10.1.1.0/24 |
+------------------+
        |
+----------------------+
| NAS                  |
| re0 10.1.1.50/24     |
| re1 192.168.42.50/24 |
+----------------------+
        |
+----------------------+
| VMFW                 |
| eth0 192.168.42.50/24|
| eth1 10.1.1.50/24   |
+----------------------+
        |
+----------------------+
| LAB 10.1.1.0/24      |
+----------------------+
```

edit don't forget a few network magic to send all network destinated to 10.1.1.50 interesting ports to 192.168.42.50.

Comment: The network ranges being the same is sort of a requirement for this setup.  The Virtual lab is supposed to be an exact (nearly) replica of production network, so don't want to even change IP addresses of hosts copied over there. And also want it isolated for user - it has a copy of our domain controller, for instance.

Comment: That is simply not feasible. As Chopper3 has already mentioned in a previous comment, it seems that you don't understand the basics of IP networking (this is a fairly fundamental principle which you are trying to contravene); please get someone to help you or start out by educating yourself on the basics before continuing this line of questioning.

Comment: not feasible? I don't know about freenas, but with freebsd you could set up jails having the same ip adress on 2 differents physical interfaces serving the same filesystems like a nas. The real hard part of the question is how to achive this in a not too dirty way with freenas inside a wm.

Comment: @bgtvfr - sorry, to be clear my comment was in reply to Adam Nofsinger's comment - not your answer.

Comment: @bgtvfr - I think you may be on to something there.  FreeNAS actually does have some capability to setup Jails (I actually had no idea what that means, but I'm thinking it is like an isolated virtual FreeNAS within FreeNAS?)  https://doc.freenas.org/9.10/freenas_jails.html  Maybe I'll head down that route and update with an answer if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think @bgtvfr has a very good, very close answer.  I've sort of given up on this whole idea for now, but I know it is possible.  The [Veeam Virtual Lab proxy](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/backup/vsphere/surebackup_ip_masquerading.html) appliance does this for us on our network, and works well, and after doing some research and looking at all of the startup scripts on this (BusyBox Linux) device, I believe the key piece of configuration I'm missing is using something like [netfilter to **mark packets**.](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html)

E.g. from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4421

> The following commands create an alternate routing table via eth1 for
>   packets that have the mark 1 (except packets to localhost). The ip
>   command is from the iproute2 suite
>
> ```
> ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1 
> ip route add 127.0.0.0/0 table 1 dev lo
> ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 table 1 dev eth1
> ```
>
> The other half of the job is recognizing packets that must get the mark 1;
>   then use iptables -t
>   mangle -A OUTPUT … -j MARK --set-mark 1 on these packets to have them
>   routed through routing table 1. I think the following should do it
>   (replace 1.2.3.4 by the address of the non-default-route interface):
>
> ```
> iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctorigdst 1.2.3.4 -j MARK --set-mark 1
> ```
>
> I'm not sure if that's enough, maybe another rule is needed on the 
>   incoming packets to tell the conntrack module to track them.

Here is the clue I found in the configuration / init file for the Veeam Proxy appliance, where eth0 and eth1 are both 10.1.1.0/24 subnet - eth0 being my production network and eth1 the virtual test lab: [image: Veeam Virtual Appliance iptables commands]
I'm just too green with netfilter/iptables, but seems like maybe this is marking packets that come in on the virtual lab interface so that they go back out on the same interface rather than the default gateway interface?